# Installing usb3 card on asus m2v motherboard

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-failure, pci-express

I have an [**ASUS M2V**](http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2/M2V/) motherboard.  I purchased a [**Transcend PCI Express**](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Transcend-Express-Interface-Dual-Expansion/dp/B003MVJG8Q) card and plugged it into the PCIe x1 port that was available.

After doing so, Windows XP doesn't pick it up at all. When started up, the computer doesn't recognize the new hardware.  I have removed all other expansion cards apart from my graphics card and still no good. I have opened up the device manager and noticed an Unknown Device under Other Device. It says its located in 'VIA Standard PCI to ISA bridge'.

This lead me to believe it was a driver issue on the motherboard so I downloaded the 4-in-1 chip set driver and installed it from the ASUS site (also tried VIA's site). Still, shows up as unknown device and the card still doesn't pick up or work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this card recognized and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another slot. You can put x1 cards into bigger slots.

Comment: wish i could, but the only other slot is for my graphics card which I can't replace.